# Html.BeginForm with null controller/action outputs wrong action url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, html.beginform

I have two `Areas`: `Profile` (for every user) and `Admin` (for admins). Some users can have Companies and manage them in their profile, and Admins can also create Companies in their area.

In the Admin area I have a `"_BaseForm"` file where I keep common code and call different partials to fill the form with fields, something like :-

```cs
var content = string.Format("~/Areas/Admin/Views/{0}/_Form.cshtml", (string)ViewBag.FolderName);

@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post,new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Partial(content)
}
```

The problem is that when I call the `Add()` function that returns the View, it gets the correct form, but the action URL corresponds to the controller/action of the `Profile Area`:-

```
<form action="/Profile/Companies/Add" ..> <!-- it should be "/Admin/Companies/Add" -->
```

When I comment the `Add (Company)` functions in the `Profile` area, it works properly.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: ....@using (Html.BeginForm("Add","Companies",FormMethod.Post,new{ area="Admin" },new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Comment: try above beginform...

Comment: thank you, but the thing is I want to keep Html.BeginForm(null,null, ..) so it can be used for other models

Comment: ok..then do it as...@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post,new{ area="Admin" },new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Comment: omg i didnt remember to do that! yes it worked thank you! :) (btw it had to be in a different order: Html.BeginForm(null,null,new { area = "Admin" },FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just correct your BeginForm as :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,new{ area="Admin" },FormMethod.Post,new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{}
```